# Is it possible to alter error message in Laravel's Validator callback?

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent

I have a custom validator set-up like this:

```
Validator::extend('valid_username', 'ProfileController@valid_username');
```

Then I have the following method which handles the validation. It checks both if the username already exists, and if the username contains valid characters.

```
public function valid_username($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $u = User::where('username', $value)->get();

    if ($u->count())
    {
        // here I would like to return "Username already taken."
        return FALSE;
    }
    else if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9@\.\-_]+$/", $value))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // here I would like to return "Username contains invalid characters."
        return FALSE;       
    }
}
```

I would like to alter the error message returned by this validator depending on which error caused the validation to fail. However, I don't know how to do this. In my language files I have set up the following line for the validator:

```
"valid_username" => "This username is already taken or contains invalid characters."
```

Is it possible with Laravel to return a specific error message? Or do I have to split this validation up in two custom validation rules? This might not be a problem in this case, but especially if database access is involved I would prefer to validate a retrieved Eloquent model in one validator instead of instantiating an Eloquent object twice.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a custom validator that uses some complex parsing logic to determine if the input is valid. The error message needs to be specifically what was wrong because "Parsing failed" is useless. I wish a validator could return a string instead of just true/false.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I would like, too. It was possible to do this in CodeIgniter. But I haven't found a way to do it in Laravel yet :(

Answer (score 8):

After consulting the code, the answer is "not out of the box". You can, however, extend everything and make that work.

The process, which I don't have time to *completely* do at the moment (sorry!), would be to create a class extending Validator, making that functionality work, and then using a new ServiceProvider to replace Laravel's `$app['validator']` with your own.

That process, a little more concretely, goes like this something like this:

```
<?php namespace MyLib\Validation;

class Validator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    // Fancy validation logic to be able to set custom messages

}
```

Then, you need to extend the Factory to return your new Validator:

```
<?php namespace MyLib\Validation;

class Factory extends \Illuminate\Validation\Factory {

    // Change this method
    /**
     * Resolve a new Validator instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @param  array  $rules
     * @param  array  $messages
     * @return \MyLib\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function resolve($data, $rules, $messages)
    {
        if (is_null($this->resolver))
        {
            // THIS WILL NOW RETURN YOUR NEW SERVICE PROVIDER SINCE YOU'RE
            // IN THE MyLib\Validation NAMESPACE
            return new Validator($this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        }
        else
        {
            return call_user_func($this->resolver, $this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        }
    }

}
```

...and finally, extend the Validation service provider, use your new Factory, and then replace the default ValidationServiceProvider with your own.

```
<?php namespace MyLib\Validation;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Validation\ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerPresenceVerifier();

        $this->app['validator'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            // THIS WILL NOW RETURN YOUR FACTORY SINCE YOU'RE
            // IN THE MyLib\Validation NAMESPACE
            $validator = new Factory($app['translator'], $app);

            // The validation presence verifier is responsible for determining the existence
            // of values in a given data collection, typically a relational database or
            // other persistent data stores. And it is used to check for uniqueness.
            if (isset($app['validation.presence']))
            {
                $validator->setPresenceVerifier($app['validation.presence']);
            }

            return $validator;
        });
    }

}
```

So anyway, that's one way to extend the Validation library with your own code. I didn't solve the issue of adding your own messages, but this will show you how, if you can read the core code and see how to add that functionality in, to go about making it work in your app.

**Last note:**

You may want to see how Laravel handles using [Database "stuff" within validation rules](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Validation/DatabasePresenceVerifier.php) - While this may not affect your application (unless it gets big!) you may want to consider using a [Repository pattern](http://vimeo.com/53029232) of some sort and using that in your `Validator::extend()` call instead of the `User` class directly. Not necessary, just a note for something to check out.

Good luck and don't be afraid to [RTFC](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFC)!

Comment: I should mention that this is good if you need to create a validation rule which might return different validation messages depending on the value, which you can't do out of the box now. Custom validation messages IS something you can get out of the box, but it's limited, and can't be done within your `Validator::extend()` call.

Comment: hey @fideloper, this really looks like you know what you're talking about ;) thanks for the detailed answer! i am not afraid to RTFC at all, but I guess it might be overkill and too time consuming at this time and size of the application. so i'll go with the KISSable solution for now. if i ever need to scale and customize the validator more this will definitely helpful. thanks, again!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making your own validation rule that does validates two things (which you shouldn't really do, validate one thing at a time), you can use the [`unique`](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique) rule and then make your own rule that validates the characters of the username.

For example:

```
$rules = ['username' => 'required|username|unique:users,username'];
```

Where the `username` rule is your custom rule that ensures it contains the correct characters.

Comment: it doesn't quite solve my issue with alternating the message output, but i do agree that it makes sense to split it up and use the unique validation rule in this case. thanks, jason!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit "dirty" but it works:

The controller validates the input with something

```php
$rules = array(
    'title' => 'no_collision:'.$input['project_id']
);
```

In the validator function flash the message to the Session before returning false:

```php
//...
public function validateNoCollision($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $project = Project::find($parameters[0]);
        if($value == $project->title){
            Session::flash('colliding_message','This collides with '.$project->title($).' created by '.$project->user->name;
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In the view do something like the following:

```html
@if($errors->has('title'))
    <span class="help-block">{{ Session::get('colliding_message') }}</span>
@endif
```